# Laravel + BrowserSync infinite loads

Tags: laravel, gulp, browser-sync

I want to setup browserSync with laravel. I have a virtual host on local machine `http://site.localhost`.

According to the manual I put this into my gulpfile.js:

```
mix.browserSync({
  proxy: 'site.localhost'
})
```

So when I run `gulp watch` I got `http://localhost:3000` open with just infinite loading. So what did I do wrong?

Comment: 1) What does your terminal show when you run `gulp watch`? 2) Do you have DNS set up for `site.localhost` in your `/etc/hosts` (or if you're using Valet)?

Comment: Try to open developer's console in chrome/ff and check - what's the target of redirects - where does your application wants to send you?

Comment: Oh my god. It's first time in my life that I made a mistake in /etc/hosts. VHost worked since I put correct config in /etc/sites-available, but made a mistake in /etc/hosts. @tptcat thank you for the tip-off!

Comment: I faced the same problem. It would be nice if you add your solution as an answer regardless of how trivial it was @Victor