# Laravel Mix + BrowserSync infinite loading out of the box

Tags: laravel, webpack, browser-sync, laravel-mix

Something's making my out-of-the-box Laravel project with `browser-sync` and the `browser-sync-webpack-plugin` installed to load infinitely on the browser-sync page. It works fine on `http://localhost`, but the browser-sync (localhost:3000) version doesn't stop loading and displays no content, just a white page.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39801873/laravel-browsersync-infinite-loads) question which was similar to mine but it doesn't have any answers.

This only recently started happening on my machine. At first I thought it was because of the antivirus or firewall but disabling them did no good. I can't even figure out what's causing the page to never load.

Here's what my **webpack.mix.js** file looks like:

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/script.js', 'public/js')
.sass('resources/assets/sass/main.scss', 'public/css')
.disableNotifications()
.browserSync();
```

**Edit**: Any tips on narrowing down the problem would also be appreciated.

[image: Infinite loading]

Comment: Are you running the application inside a homestead box? or valet ? Have you tried in other browsers? (should not matter but maybe?). Are you using a mac/windows machine, because i recall reading about localhost issues on mac/valet .
Some info that might be useful to add to your question.

Comment: No, not using homestead or vallet; tried it in all browsers to no avail. It's a windows machine so I guess that rules out the mac issue too. Any ideas to see where it's stuck? Like what's causing the infinite load?

Comment: Have you tried to hardcode the proxy to the url you have defined in your host file? 
```browserSync({
    proxy: 'my-domain.test'
})```

Comment: I had to add my-domain.test in the hosts file and it worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me, the problem was adding to the windows hosts file whatever url browsersync was proxying to, and point it to 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 2):

The default proxy target for the mix-browsersync package used in Laravel is `app.test`.

You can specify a different proxy target in the mix file:

```
mix
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .browserSync('localhost');
```

And, if like me, you're using the artisan server for development, you can even target that (as long as you're running `php artisan serve` in you project):

```
mix
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .browserSync('localhost:8000');
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a possible solution for you that worked for me.

My issue was that I was fixated on using the `localhost:8000`; instead I tried `127.0.0.1:8000`. For those of you who don't know, that IP address is your default localhost IP address.

Try adding it like this to you `webpack.mix.js` file \/\/\/

```
mix.browserSync({
    proxy: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'
});
```

Or alternatively you can use

mix.browserSync('127.0.0.1:8000');

Once done you can run `npm run watch`.